# Visual Studio 2015 Error : MSB4057 The target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" does not exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I am getting this error while building the new created Apache Cordova (javascript) project in Visual Studio 2015 (Fresh Install without any other installed verson):

Error MSB4057

The target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" does not exist in the project.
BlankCordovaApp1 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. To solve it I installed TypeScript 1.7.4.0. I got mine from the installation image. Look into the folder ServicedSetupPayloads ->OfflineCache->installers->TypeScriptV5->en->0.

Hope that will help you.